# How to redirect Wordpress blog through IIS in combination with existing ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wordpress, iis

I started installing (through the Web Installer Platform) a Wordpress blog on my **Windows (2012) Server**.

On this server I'm already hosting a ASP.NET MVC 4.5 site.

Now, before I can proceed configuring the Wordpress site (by opening www.***.com/wp-config.php),

I seem to create a new redirect rule in **IIS / web.config**.

Otherwise it will give conflicts with the existing ASP.NET site.

I have tried this redirect rule:

```
<rule name="wordpress blog" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(blog)" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
</rule>
```

With this rule, when opening https://www.****.com/blog/wp-config.php I end up with a runtime error on https://www.****.com/blog/error?aspxerrorpath=/blog/wp-config.php

And when adding in www.***.com/wp-config.php (so in the root folder)

```
<rule name="block" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^blog$" />
    <action type="none" />
</rule>
```

and going to https://www.***.com/blog/wp-config.php, I am getting the same errorpage as above.

I can't seem to figure out how this rule should look like. Is there anyone who can help me out there?

Comment: According to your description, I still couldn't understand your url rewrite rule clearly. Do you mean you want www.***.com/**blog/**wp-config.php/ to t www.***.com/index.php ? Besides, I suggest you could post the details error message about the 500 error,

Comment: No, i mean to exclude www.**.com/blog from the ASP.NET rewrite logic, so that the wordpress blog pages do not conflict with the ASP.NET pages.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use belwo url rewrite rule in the asp.net application.

This rule will redirect all the request with blob to the index.php.

```
<rule name="wordpress blog" >
      <match url="blog/(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
       </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{yourdomian}/blog/index.php"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: I have proceeded a little bit:
When I go to https://www.**mydomain**.com/en/blog/wp-admin/install.php?step=1 it will show me the installation step (step 1). 
But this page is unstyled, because the CSS is not loaded, probably because of the still incorrect rewrite configuration. 

When I continue and fill the fields and click submit, then the page takes me to step 2, but because of incorrect rewrite the url becomes then https://www.**mydomain.com**/en/install.php?step=2 so without the /blog/wp-admin and I get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by adding "blog" in the global.asax.cs in the ExclusionFilter as follows:

i18n.UrlLocalizer.QuickUrlExclusionFilter = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?:sitemap.xml|.css|.jpg|.png|.svg|.woff|.woff2|.eot|.js|.html|.json)$|(?:**blog**)");